# Why is "raise" a statement, rather than a function?

Tags: python

As far as I can tell, `raise` would function just as well if it were a function, rather than a statement.

A distinctive feature of statements seems to me to be that their arguments aren't interpreted as "code". E.g. `import math` doesn't require you to have defined `math`, and a similar function would require a string argument: `import("math")`.

Another is that, if an argument is to be interpreted as code, it's not necessarily evaluated.  E.g. `assert testbool, myfunc()` will only call `myfunc()` if `testbool` is `True`.

Lastly, I imagine that using a statement rather than a function avoids a bit of overhead due to calling a function.

None of these advantages apply to `raise`: its argument always already has to be defined, and there is no situation in which the `raise` statement is executed, but its argument is not evaluated. Lastly, I imagine the overhead of calling a function to be insignificant compared to all the other book-keeping involved in raising an exception.

At the same time, having `raise` as a statement comes at the cost of not being able to use the word `raise` as the name of a variable, which would see plenty of uses, considering it's a decently common English verb. (I can raise a platform, raise a number by 1, ...)

I also imagine having fewer statements would simplify compilers.

So why is `raise` a statement?

Comment: Why the downvotes, BTW?

Comment: the cost of not being able to use `raise` is not worth this approach.  what would you call the builtin function? `raise()` ?.  you 'could' then use raise as a variable (or even a function),  but that would wipe out its intended use as a function to raise exceptions.  and that would confuse everyone who looked at your code.  especially if you created a different function called raise.

Comment: @ShpielMeister: The same argument holds for any other builtin. Of course you should know what you're doing if you create a variable called "id" or "print" or "sum" (or "raise"). But there's plenty of situations where you don't need the builtin, and re-using the name can be an okay solution.

Comment: you won't find many experienced programmers re-using a name without a **very** strong reason.   you haven't provided onw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because making it a statement allows it to be compiled to dedicated bytecode, which the interpreter loop uses to handle exiting the normal flow and entering the exception handling stage, which involves exiting function stacks in a different manner from a regular `return`.

If you made it a function, you can't do any of this. The function would have to call back into the interpreter loop to alter the state.

Moreover, raising and handling exceptions are core to the language, just like `return` is in a function. You want to give *other tools* the ability to detect such use; `raise` is an important event in the flow of code, to the point that it doesn't just matter to the Python interpreter. Code analysis tools should be able to detect it too, without having to distinguish between `raise` used as the original built-in function versus all the other possible assignments, or even rebindings of the function.

Comment: Could the same not be accomplished within a dedicated function with minimal extra overhead though?

Comment: @acdr: why would you do that? That would immensely complicate the interpreter loop design.

Comment: while I imagine that might be the case (due to exceptions propagating to the calling function), I don't see how that's *necessarily* true. Would you happen to have a link explaining this in detail?

Comment: @acdr: I can only link to the current implementation of the `RAISE_VARARGS` opcode, which uses `goto fast_block_end` to jump to the exception flow. You'd have to imagine the interpreter loop having to check for this condition at the start of each loop instead, after a function has set the flags to trigger the state.

Comment: @acdr exception handling is subtle.   it's not so much the overhead of a function call, it's the additional complexity to the stack that using a function entails.   when an exception is raised you may already be handling an exception which has run into additional problems.   for example, if you were writing to a security logfile as part of your an exception handling and it runs out of space you would certainly not want to try log the failure to the very same file which you couldn't write, too. using a function invites more edge cases